# How can I provide runtime parameter/argument values via a file for CDAP pipleline

Tags: cdap

How do i add run time parameter/arguments to CDAP pipeline.

We can set parameters in all the Transforms, Source and Target nodes and manually enter the values at run time in the Datafusion environments.

However in a production environments i would want a parameter file to feed the values to the pipeline, how do i  achieve this functionality.

In the CDAP documentation i don't find anything useful regarding the run time arguments. I am new to datafusion and am not very familiar with the interface. If this question is already answered a redirect to the thread will also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting a pipeline, you can specify runtime arguments as a JSON map in the request body.

First, your pipeline should contain property lookup macros, which are documented [here](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/developer-manual/pipelines/creating-pipelines.html#field-macro-substitution).
As an example, a pipeline json definition could contain the following configuration for the BigQuery Sink plugin (surrounding fields removed for brevity):

```
  {
    "name": "BigQuerySink",
    "plugin": {
      "properties": {
        "table": "${bqsink_table}"
      }
    },
```

Then, when starting your pipeline, you can specify the value(s) for the macros, as mentioned [here](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/lifecycle.html#start-a-program).

In this example, you would send a POST request to `v3/namespaces/<namespace-id>/apps/<app-id>/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start`, with request body:

```
{ "bqsink_table": "myTable" }
```

Comment: I should add, if you instead prefer to set the default values for all parameters at once, you can use the [Preferences API](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/preferences.html#preferences-http-restful-api)