# How to set runtime arguments in a CDAP/DATA FUSION pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

In addition to Argument Setter Plugin, is there any other way to set runtime arguments in a pipeline? For example，I calculated the total number of error messages，and I want to set in a runtime argument so that the email sender can use it? Someone can take a look and help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please check following thread on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677435/how-can-i-provide-runtime-parameter-argument-values-via-a-file-for-cdap-piplelin/59759179#59759179 where you can find method with specifying runtime arguments as a JSON map in the request body. Let me know if it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can set the runtime argument of a pipeline.

1. [Argument Setter action-plugin](https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter)
2. [GCS Argument Setter action-plugin](https://github.com/data-integrations/google-cloud/blob/develop/docs/GCSArgumentSetter-action.md)
3. [Preferences and Runtime Arguments](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/480314690/Preferences+and+Runtime+Arguments)
4. [Setting Preferences](https://datafusion.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/32276562/Setting+Preferences)