# workflow token in CDF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

Is Workflow Token feature available in CDF?

The usecase I see is that some variables can be pushed to workflow level and passed to subsequent pipeline(application) which could be very handy feature.

At present, If pipeline_1 > pipeline_2 > pipeline_3 is the sequence and pipeline_3 needs some arguments, those need to be passed right from pipeline_1 to 2 and then to 3. This gets complex when there are N no of pipelines. Can workflow token feature address this issue?

Namespace preferences is another feature which helps out.

Comment: Check this detailed SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509570 on how to set up one pipeline to trigger another pipeline; you can set a runtime variable in the first pipeline and this variable will be set in the triggered pipelines.

Comment: @RallyH, thanks for the answer. That approach works however issue is If pipeline_3 needs some parameters, those needs to be passed right from pipeline_1 to _2 and then to _3. This is an overhead. on CDAP help, workflow token is mentioned which kind of pushes variables at higher level than pipeline and is accessible to any pipeline. This is how I interpreted it. This becomes very handy.

Comment: It's not very clear. A schema can help to understand! And do you talk about Cloud Workflow?