# Google CDF: Can we set the value of a column as a runtime argument?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am getting a value returned by hitting a HTTP endpoint which I am storing in a column. Now a want to trigger another Http Endpoint with the value in the column. But the HTTP endpoint takes hardcoded values or macros only. So I want to know if I can set a run-time argrument based on the column value

Please suggest How I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of setting runtime arguments:

1. Using [Argument Setter Plugin](https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter) - type of Action plugin that allows one to create reusable pipelines by dynamically substituting the configurations that can be served by an HTTP Server.
2. Specifying runtime arguments as a JSON map in the request body, when [starting an program](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.1.3/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/lifecycle.html#start-a-program).
3. [CDAP Preferences](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.1.3/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/preferences.html) HTTP RESTful API.

I recommend you check the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline#set_the_macro_arguments) for Datafusion, where you can find a way of setting variables/macros using the GCS bucket.

Additionally, have a look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677435/how-can-i-provide-runtime-parameter-argument-values-via-a-file-for-cdap-piplelin/59759179#59759179) on SO. It describes the method with specifying runtime arguments as a JSON map in the request body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with argument setter we have to make the object public I presume. So in google if a object is public and if you update it , it takes 1 hour to reflect the latest result in public URL. So how my pipeline takes the latest arguments in that case.